# Conversion of Date to UNIX Timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a JavaScript function running in Google Drive folder of many spreadsheets that is currently logging dates into the log;

```
function convertDates(){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Conversion Started With First Row Date Cells','Conversion', 5);
    Logger.log('Date Conversion Started');
    var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
    var cell = activeCell.getValue();
    Logger.log(cell);
 }
```

How would one convert the output of 'cell' which currently looks like:

```
 May 03, 2014 at 05:19PM
```

Into a Unix Time stamp within Javascript? I am inclined to believe that this can involve the Date() function but am unsure.

Thank's in Advance.

Comment: If a cell contains a value that Sheets recognizes as a date, then `getValue()` will give you a js Date object, regardless of how the date is _formatted_ in the sheet. Are you sure you have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way to remove "at" and the sheet then recognizes the value as a valid date.

```js
function convertDates(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = sheet.getRange(1, 1);

  range_input = range_input.getValue();
  range_input = range_input.replace("at ", " ");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(range_input);
}
```

I am just replacing for one single cell. You can loop that to all the needed cell values.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the get a string representation of the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (january 1, 1970) you can use a code like this :

```
function convertDates(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Conversion Started With First Row Date Cells','Conversion', 5);
  Logger.log('Date Conversion Started');
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
  var unixEpoch = new Date(1970,0,1,0,0,0).getTime();// difference between JS epoch and UNIX epoch in milliseconds
  var cell = ((activeCell.getValue().getTime()-unixEpoch)/1000).toString();
  Logger.log(cell);
  activeCell.setValue(cell);// this will write it back to the sheet... be careful, it is not a date object anymore but a string... so the code won't work after that.
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove "at" and to add a space after "05:19".

Look like this :

```
var date = new Date("May 03, 2014 05:19 PM");
```